# Existing LCD & LED software to edit

Tags: software-development, binary-data

How to edit LCD or LED software without smart or any source code to make it own changes?

And I had .bin extension software but I’m not able to open it because it’s binary file. I tried to edit using iso software’s but couldn’t.

Is that possible to edit that ?